# ipad setting a uiview controller

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have this code

```
arrangeListViewController = [[[ArrangeListViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
arrangeList = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(attributesPadding, y, popoverWidth - 2* attributesPadding, popoverHeight - y - attributesPadding) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
arrangeList.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
```

So i add this "arrangeList to my view and i can see it. But how do i go about assigning the view controller for "arrangeList'?

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what you mean mate... if you want to add the table view to the `arrangeListViewController` then do this:

```
[arrangeListViewController.view addSubview:arrangeList];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:arrangeListViewController animated:YES];
```